# How can the member objects be changed at run time in composition?

Tags: c++, oop, composition

From **Thinking in C++ Vol. 1** (P-33):

> Composition comes with a great deal of flexibility. The member
>   objects of your new class are usually private, making them
>   inaccessible to the client programmers who are using the class. This
>   allows you to change those members without disturbing existing
>   client code.
>   ***You can also change the member objects at runtime, to
>   dynamically change the behavior of your program. Inheritance,
>   which is described next, does not have this flexibility since the
>   compiler must place compile-time restrictions on classes created
>   with inheritance.***

How can we change the member objects at run time in composition?
Aren't the objects included when the class declaration are written?

`class car`
`{`
`private:`
`engine obj;`
`}`

So, here the class `car` contains the object of class `engine`. How can we change this at runtime?

Or am I missing some point?

Comment: This is basically pointing towards one of design patterns called **Strategy**, If you read more about it You will be able to answer your Q yourself.

Comment: Ah, this bold italic font on SO is barely readable :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a pointer to your member object instead:

```
class car {
    engine *obj;
}
```

Now you can choose at runtime whether to use an instance of `rotary_engine` or `v8_engine` or `flux_capacitor_engine`.

Of course you may want to use something like a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` to manage the ownership and lifetime of the member object.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed a bit vague statement.

Composition defines a `has-a` relationship, i.e. **`car` has `engine`**. You can exchange the engine of your car and car will still remain a car.

Inheritance defines a `is-a` relationship, i.e. if you had defined car as inheriting from engine, that would mean **`car` is an `engine`**. Changing the engine would mean change in the type of car itself - if you change the base class it automatically changes the derived class. This constrain doesn't exist when using composition.

So in your example composition is the correct way.

Comment: Beware that this "composition->has, inheritace->is" is true only for Java (OOP-only) languages. C++ can be used also in different ways: private and protected inheritance is a form of composition (and public inheritance is an *anonymous composition*, by a compiler standpoint) and CRTP inheritance on traits classes can be used to trigger *polymorphic composition* as well.   Not to mention the fact that "to be" and "to have" can be swapped in verbal forms: you can *have* long hairs or *be* log haired.  So use this discrimination with care, since the world outside may not be THAT simple.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia yes, I was talking about the `public` inheritance which is the only one relevant when comparing to composition; `protected` and `private` serve different design purposes. Regarding CRTP - this is is actually a technique, and while your remark is correct, I was referring to a **concept** of composition vs. inheritance, not to the possibility to achieve one or another via various techniques. Your example, however, is incorrect in my opinion. If you *have* a long hair that doesn't mean you *are* a long hair. But that's a different broad design topic, long away from this question

Comment: AH.... yes... you can have *somebody else* long hair! Especially if you descend from Cherokee! (you had by iheritance!)  Jokes apart, although I don't agree with some of your assertions, the fact both mine  and yours exist and works is the demonstration things cannot be simplified as such.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia that's true, `is-a` is not always corresponding perfectly to a human language usage. The classic example is a square inheriting from a rectangle. It's correct mathematically but wrong from software design aspect. But again - it's a different question out of OP's question scope.

Answer (score 0):

For pure composition, runtime changes are also possible:

```
class Car {
private:
   CarPart &get_part(int i) const { 
        switch(i) {
            case 0: return e;
            case 1: return w1;
            case 2: return w2;
            case 3: return w3;
            case 4: return w4;
        }
   }
private:
   Engine e;
   Wheel w1, w2, w3, w4;
};
```

Then for example setting properties is easy:

```
void set_property(int id, std::string name, int value) {
    CarPart &p = get_part(id);
    p.set(name, value);
}
```

This is about as dynamic as you can get...